# AWS Lambda new line using boto3

Tags: python, aws-lambda

This should be quite straightforward but I'm a bit stuck. I have a Lambda function in AWS that sends out daily email with FX rates, I'm just trying to add a new line in the body of the email that gets sent out using boto3 but '\n' doesn't seem to work, any thoughts? I have copied the code below with some placeholders for sender and receiver email addresses.

```
import yfinance as yf
import json
import boto3


class LambdaHandler:
    def __init__(self,event, context):
        self.event = event
        self.context = context
        self.FX_rates = {"eur_usd": yf.Ticker('EURUSD=X').history(period='30d')['Close'],
                    "gbp_usd": yf.Ticker('GBPUSD=X').history(period='30d')['Close'],
                    "gbp_eur": yf.Ticker('GBPEUR=X').history(period='30d')['Close'],
                    "gbp_aud": yf.Ticker('GBPAUD=X').history(period='30d')['Close']
                    }

        # Daily change
        self.Dailys = {fx: (fx_data[-1]/fx_data[-2]-1)*100 for fx, fx_data in self.FX_rates.items()}

        # Weekly change
        self.Weeklys = {fx: (fx_data[-1]/fx_data[-7]-1)*100 for fx, fx_data in self.FX_rates.items()}


        # Monthly change
        self.Monthlys = {fx: (fx_data[-1]/fx_data[-30]-1)*100 for fx, fx_data in self.FX_rates.items()}


        # FX rates formatted
        self.rounded_FX = {
                    "eur_usd": round(self.FX_rates['eur_usd'][0],2),
                    "gbp_usd": round(self.FX_rates['gbp_usd'][0],2),
                    "gbp_eur": round(self.FX_rates['gbp_eur'][0],2),
                    "gbp_aud": round(self.FX_rates['gbp_aud'][0],2)
        }

    def to_f_statement(self, rate):
        return "{}%".format("%.2f" % rate)
        

    def send_email(self):
        ses = boto3.client("ses", region_name="eu-west-2")
        sent_from = "SENDER EMAIL ADDRESS"
        receiver_email = "RECEIVER EMAIL ADDRESS"
        body = f'Current FX rates: EUR to USD {self.rounded_FX["eur_usd"]}, GBP to USD {self.rounded_FX["gbp_usd"]}, GBP to EUR {self.rounded_FX["gbp_eur"]}, GBP to AUD {self.rounded_FX["gbp_aud"]}. ' \
                '\n'\
                f'Daily changes: EUR to USD {self.to_f_statement(self.Dailys["eur_usd"])}, GBP to USD {self.to_f_statement(self.Dailys["gbp_usd"])}, GBP to EUR {self.to_f_statement(self.Dailys["gbp_eur"])},' \
               f'GBP to AUD {self.to_f_statement(self.Dailys["gbp_aud"])}' \
                f'\n'\
               f'Weekly changes: EUR to USD {self.to_f_statement(self.Weeklys["eur_usd"])}, GBP to USD {self.to_f_statement(self.Weeklys["gbp_usd"])}, GBP to EUR {self.to_f_statement(self.Weeklys["gbp_eur"])},' \
               f' GBP to AUD {self.to_f_statement(self.Weeklys["gbp_aud"])}' \
                f'\n'\
               f' Monthly changes: EUR to USD {self.to_f_statement(self.Monthlys["eur_usd"])}, GBP to USD {self.to_f_statement(self.Monthlys["gbp_usd"])}, GBP to EUR {self.to_f_statement(self.Monthlys["gbp_eur"])},' \
               f' GBP to AUD {self.to_f_statement(self.Monthlys["gbp_aud"])}'
        CHARSET = "UTF-8"
    
        html = """\
    
        %s
        """ % (body)
    
        response = ses.send_email(
            Destination={
                "ToAddresses": [
                    receiver_email,
                ],
            },
            Message={
                "Body": {
                    "Html": {
                        "Charset": CHARSET,
                        "Data": html,
                    }
                },
                "Subject": {
                    "Charset": CHARSET,
                    "Data": "Daily FX rates",
                },
            },
            Source=sent_from,
        )
    
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Ready to go!')
        }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return LambdaHandler(event, context).send_email()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are sending a plain text email, but passing the email body into the `Html` attribute instead of the `Text` attribute. So the email is being sent as HTML and your email client is rendering it as HTML. Newlines are ignored in HTML.

You either need to change your newline `\n` characters into HTML `<br>` line break tags, or you need to just pass your current email body as `Text` instead of `Html`.